# VMWare Server inventory directory for ISO images

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, iso-image, vmware-server

I'm trying to create a Virtual Machine in VMWare Server for Linux. I'm at the part where it asks for an ISO image. The inventory is empty. I don't know what directory this actually corresponds to on my Linux system. I tried moving the .iso to my home directory but VMWare still does not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in /var/lib/vmware/Virtual Machines. I found out by going back and looking at the output of the install script. I'm glad I didn't close the terminal window, otherwise I don't know how I would have found it out.